# Term: Retrograde Translations

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Let's start with an example. I asked this question over on CN@SE: [Translation: “世界上，治疗心脏病最好的方式就是不要开刀。”](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/12093/4136). In the question I asked for a translation of an, apparently, well-known English quote.

The quote as been translated from English to Chinese, and now I'm trying to find the original English.

In the question I called it a `retrograde translation` but is there a proper term for this type of translation?

Answer (score 4):

This is generally called ***back-translation***, if you are **translating** the text back into its original language.

> A "back-translation" is a translation of a translated text back into the language of the original text, made without reference to the original text.
>
> Comparison of a back-translation with the original text is sometimes used as a check on the accuracy of the original translation, much as the accuracy of a mathematical operation is sometimes checked by reversing the operation.
>
> In the context of machine translation, a back-translation is also called a "round-trip translation."
>
> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation#Back-translation)

If you are simply trying to **find** the original quote, then back-translation will be a start in that process (in narrowing down the context and providing an approximation), but the quote you find will not be a back-translation: it will be the original.